# Why does Phone storage get full with ambiguous "Other" storage that wont let me use more than one GB of the supposed four that i have

Tags: internal-storage

My HTC keeps running out of phone storage, there is supposed to be four GB of storage but it always gets full at one GB of app data and 3 gigs of "Other" data which isn't cache and I can't even see what it is, I've had this problem with previous HTC phones, I've done what I can to move as many apps to my SD card but most can be moved there. What is this Other, is it important data, and can i move it or get rid of it.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click it for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Have you checked what is shown when it connects to the PC? Does this memory appear when you connect to PC?
Try using a file manager to browse the files of your phone, and look for anything unusual.

Answer (score 1):

"Other" is just anything that doesn't fall into one of the other categories.  If you install a file-manager app (such as [OI File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.openintents.filemanager)) you can browse through the actual files and see exactly what's there.